# Get the outer shape of a MultiLineString

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, extents, linestring

i have a bunch of shapely MultiLineStrings, which I would like to "convert" to Polygons so that the "outer" boundaries of the MultiLineStrings serve as edges.

One of my MultiLineStrings looks like this:

[image]

Using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = my_gdf.geometry.iloc[0].convex_hull
ax = my_gdf.geometry.iloc[:1].plot()
x,y = x.exterior.xy
ax.plot(x, y)
```

, I can obtain the convex hull, resulting in:

[image]

However, what I would like to have is something like:

[image]

(note, that the outer blue line is the convex hull)

Is there a `shapely` operation or similar in Python, that can give me this "outer boundary"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New Answer:

It turned out, the thing I was looking for was the so-called **concave hull**, or **alpha shape** of the string. There are implementations to calculate the alpha shape, and I found one [particularly helpful post on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378168/9665523). The only drawback is that alpha has to be chosen for each set of points within the MultiLineString individually. This alpha can be optimized by `alphashape` but the time it takes seems to scale with the number of points.

```
import alphashape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
from descartes import PolygonPatch

# Get Points from MultiLineString
# mls is a MultiLineString
points = []
for line in mls:
    for c in line.coords:
        points.append(c)
points = np.array(points)

# Get optimal alpha and alpha shape
alpha = 0.95 * alphashape.optimizealpha(points, lower=0, upper=0.01, max_iterations=100)
hull = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha)
hull_pts = hull.exterior.coords.xy

# Plot it
ax = gdf.iloc[1:2].plot()
ax.scatter(hull_pts[0], hull_pts[1], color='red')
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(hull, fill=True, color='green'))
```

[image]

I might still need to resample some points on the lines, but otherwise it's great.

### Old:

After some tinkering, I found a solution by myself:

**Edit: This only works when the MultiLineString forms some sort of Linear Ring. When Lines are not connected, `polygonize` returns an empty list.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import polygonize, unary_union

multi = MultiPolygon(list(polygonize(my_gdf.geometry.iloc[0])))
poly = unary_union(mp)

ax = my_gdf.geometry.iloc[:1].plot()
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
ax.plot(x, y, color="orange")
```

[image]

The orange line is the boundary of the `poly` polygon, encompassing all the lines of the multilinestring.